# Dataframe sorting using multiple columns using key function

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I am trying to sort a dataframe.

> df.sort_values(by=["A",'B'],  key = lambda x : x.map(custom_dict), ascending=[None, False])

Let's say there are 2 columns and I wanna sort the dataframe sorting by A first with key function with my own list, and sorting by B column in descending order. Therefore, I wrote above line but it didn't work..

I need your help :(

Comment: What does "key function with my own list" mean?

Comment: Please share a sample inout with expected output.